# no fill for secondary points in a ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

I have two problems with my plot below. First, how can I get my 3 black points to have no fill? Second, how can I have a `geom_smooth()` for those 3 black points?

I have tried something for both without success.

```
dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/cw2.csv')
dat$groups <- factor(dat$groups)

dat2 <- dat %>% group_by(groups) %>% summarize(mean_x = mean(x),
                                       mean_y = mean(y),
                                       .groups = 'drop')

dat %>% group_by(groups) %>% ggplot() +
  aes(x, y, color = groups, shape = groups)+
  geom_point(size = 2) + theme_classic()+ 
  stat_ellipse(level = .6) +
geom_point(data = dat2, 
           mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y), fill = NA, ### No fill 
           size = 4, color = 1, show.legend = F) +
  geom_smooth(data = dat2, mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y), 
method = "lm", se=F, color = 1, formula = 'y ~ x')  ## geom_smooth doesn't show
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with the `geom_smooth` is that it's inheriting the `color = groups` aesthetic, and trying to smooth each point individually (even though you have `color = 1`). Pass `inherit.aes = FALSE` to that layer and the smooth will show up. (Or `group = 1` inside `aes()`, as in Duck's answer).

Comment: He doesn't use spaces - do a "Find" on the page for `group=1` and you will see it in the "for smooth try this" code block.

Comment: It's an argument to `geom_smooth()`, not to `aes()`.

Comment: Only way I can think to get the same shape but filled/non filled points as you want is to (a) combine `dat2` and `dat` into 1 data frame, (b) create a "data source" column (`"original" for rows from `dat` and `"summary"` for the rows in `dat2`), (c) create an interaction column combining the data source column and the group column, and (d) map `shape` to the interaction column and do a manual `shape` scale picking out the solid vs hollow PCH shapes as appropriate, and (e) plotting all the points in one `geom_point()` layer, while using appropriate subsets for the eillpise and smooth layers.

Comment: I don't have the time to work out the details right now.... It sounds like a pain, but it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for non filled points:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
dat %>% group_by(groups) %>% ggplot() +
  aes(x, y, color = groups, shape = groups)+
  geom_point(size = 2) + theme_classic()+ 
  stat_ellipse(level = .6) +
  geom_point(data = dat2, 
             mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y,fill = factor(groups)), 
             size = 4, show.legend = F,shape=21) +
  geom_smooth(data = dat2, mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y), 
              method = "lm", se=F, color = 1, formula = 'y ~ x')  ## geom_smooth doesn't show
```

Output:

[image]

For smooth try this:

```
#Code 2
dat %>% group_by(groups) %>% ggplot() +
  aes(x, y, color = groups, shape = groups)+
  geom_point(size = 2) + theme_classic()+ 
  stat_ellipse(level = .6) +
  geom_point(data = dat2, 
             mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y,fill = factor(groups)),
             size = 4, show.legend = F,shape=21) +
  geom_smooth(data = dat2, mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y,group=1), 
              method = "lm", se=F, color = 1, formula = 'y ~ x')+
  scale_fill_manual(values=rep('black',3))
```

Output:

[image]

Try this for keeping same shape:

```
#Code 3
dat %>% group_by(groups) %>% ggplot() +
  aes(x, y, color = groups, shape = groups)+
  geom_point(size = 2) + theme_classic()+ 
  stat_ellipse(level = .6) +
  geom_point(data = dat2, 
             mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y,color = factor(groups)),
             size = 4, show.legend = F,color='black') +
  geom_smooth(data = dat2, mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y,group=1), 
              method = "lm", se=F, color = 1, formula = 'y ~ x')+
  scale_fill_manual(values=rep('black',3))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I have added an update for what you want. Hope that helps!

Comment: It does and thank you so very much! I'll be asking some follow-up questions.